# How to reproduce this type of server-side authentication?

Tags: sql, database, authentication

A Server Connection that I have is username and password protected, and so this prompt pops up when you open the mxd. I am trying to understand the system we have here better, and would like to be pointed towards a resource that explains how to set this up. I am unsure if this is an ArcGIS or a server feature.

[image: I want to learn more about this this kind of authentication]

Comment: Have a look at the help file [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/databases/database-connections-desktop.htm).